# Laravel 5 check whether a user is logged in

Tags: authentication, laravel, filter, url-routing, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel 5 and trying to understand its `Auth` process. I want to prevent user to reach some of my pages unless the user is not logged in. Trying to make it with `Route:filter` but it does not work. What i have done wrong ?

```
Route::filter('/pages/mainpage', function()
{
    if(!Auth::check()) 
    {
        return Redirect::action('PagesController@index');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You should use the [`auth` middleware](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/authentication#protecting-routes). In your route just add it like this:

```
Route::get('pages/mainpage', ['middleware' => 'auth', 'uses' => 'FooController@index']);
```

Or in your controllers constructor:

```
public function __construct(){
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

Comment: getting the error View [app] not found. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\AutoQlik\resources\views\auth\login.blade.php)

Comment: Then you either have to create that view or change the redirect in `app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php`

Comment: what if i need route for any url on my site to be filtered through auth middleware

Comment: @HosMercury You can wrap the routes in a group and apply the middleware to the group

Answer (score 36):

use

```
Auth::check()
```

more here https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#authenticating-users in Determining If The Current User Is Authenticated

Answer (score 24):

**you can do this directly in your blade code by this way**

```
@if (!Auth::guest())
        do this 
@else
        do that
@endif
```

Comment: The new way is `@auth` and `@endauth` https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#if-statements but +1 anyway

Answer (score 11):

You can use `middleware` in controller

1. All actions in controller require to be logged in

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

2. Or you can check it in action

```
public function create()
{
    if (Auth::user()) {   // Check is user logged in
        $example= "example";
        return View('novosti.create')->with('example', $example);
    } else {
        return "You can't access here!";
    }
}
```

3. Also you can use it on route

```
Route::get('example/index', ['middleware' => 'auth', 'uses' => 'example@index']);
```

Answer (score 11):

in laravel  you can check if user is logged in blade or not logged.
**in page blade use this code:**

```
@auth

    // The user is login...

@endauth


@guest

    // The user is not login...

@endguest
```

Answer (score 3):

if you want authentication middleware for single route then

```
// Single route

Route::get("/awesome/sauce", "AwesomeController@sauce", ['middleware' => 'auth']);
```

if you want auth middlesware on multiples routes then use :

```
// Route group

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
// lots of routes that require auth middleware
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can as well perform the below

@guest

//Whatever you want the guest to see goes here

@else

//Whatever is reserved for the privileged users goes here

@endguest

```
@guest
//Guest area
@else
//Privileged area
@endguest
```