# Laravel observer check if user is logged

Tags: php, laravel

I have observer:

```
<?php

namespace App\Observers;

use App\Comment;

class CommentObserver
{
    /**
     * Handle the Comment "created" event.
     *
     * @param  \App\Comment $comment
     * @return void
     */
    public function created(Comment $comment)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

I need to check if a user is logged. Can I add A user model to check if a user is logged? I need process this observe only if user is guest.

Middleware not working in observe.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5 check whether a user is logged in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30118234/laravel-5-check-whether-a-user-is-logged-in)

Comment: @KamaleshM.Talaviya is wrong. On observe middleware is not working

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Auth::check()` to check whether user is logged in or not.

Add `use \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth` in the Header of the file

```
if(!Auth::check()){
    //user is guest
}else{
    $user = Auth::user();
}
```