# Redirect to other route when session has expired in Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, logout, laravel-5.8

I´m trying to return another route because in my case login it´s a modal page, and when the session has expired, return to this route but it does not exist. I don´t know how I would do this.

I can see this in web: `if(Auth::check()){ return route('/')}`  but i don´t know where i´m putting this code.

Also i can see this: in 'App\Exception\Handler' put this:

```
if ($exception instanceof AuthenticationException) {
            return redirect('/');
        }
```

How I would can to do this?

Thanks for helping me

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/middleware

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 5 check whether a user is logged in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30118234/laravel-5-check-whether-a-user-is-logged-in)

Comment: Thanks for all response. but i don´t understand very well all responses. Where would can i do this... i want to use middleware, but i don´t know how i can to do it

Answer (score 0):

You can create a route to check sessions, every minute it will check session exists or not.
You can use like this:

Blade part:

```
@if (Auth::user())
  <script>
    $(function() {
      setInterval(function checkSession() {
        $.get('/is-logged-in', function(data) {
          // if session was expired
          if (!data.isLoggedIn) {
            // redirect to login page    
            // or, may be better, just reload page
            location.reload();
          }
        });
      }, 60000); // You can change it
    });
  </script>
@endif
```

Route:

```
Route::get('is-logged-in', 'Auth\AuthController@checkSession');
```

Controller:

```
public function checkSession()
{
    return Response::json(['isLoggedIn' => Auth::check()]);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response, but, i need change dafault value laravel session expired

Answer (score 0):

Laravel probably already has what you need. Take a look at the `App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate` class. This is a middleware that will redirect user to 'login' named route (by default), if the session has expired.
By default none of the routes you put in `routes/web.php` are protected by this middleware, but you can change this.

Method 1: Add a `auth` middleware in your controller's constructor:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

Method 2: Add a `auth` middleware for one of your routes:

```
Route::get('profile', function () {
    // Only authenticated users may enter...
})->middleware('auth');
```

Method 3: Adding all protected routes into group:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
    // All your protected routes go here
});
```

Then you can easily change the URL which will be used for redirecting users with expired session (not authenticated). Just edit the `App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::redirectTo()` method and return your URL, for example:

```
protected function redirectTo($request)
{
    if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
        return route('yourLoginRouteName');
    }
}
```